# When can we extend a measure from a sub $\sigma$-algebra to the $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal F)$ be a Borel measure space and let $\mathcal G\subseteq F$ be a Borel sub $\sigma$-algebra (or maybe the topology generating $\mathcal G$ is included in the topology generating $\mathcal F$). Suppose that $(X,\mathcal G,\mu)$ is a measure space. Is it always possible to extend $\mu$ to the measure space $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$ such that for any $\mathcal G$ measurable function $f$ on $X$, $\mu(f)$ is preserved.

---

Here is my motivation for this problem. If we take the Borel  $\sigma$-algebra generated by a Banach space $X$ to be $\mathcal F$ and the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the weak topology to be $\mathcal G$ then the constraint is satisfied, now it is easier to get statement like for all measure $\mu$ on $X$, there is $x\in X$ such that for all continuous affine function $f$ on $X$, $\mu(f)=f(x)$ (and things about uniqueness) in the weak topology and I want to see what they imply in the strong topology.

Comment: Fair enough, what if we go from weak to strong topology on some Banach space then ? (Since that is actually the case I'm interested in))

Comment: Well, you make me doubt about it, but I would say yes. In "Phelps, Robert R. Lectures on Choquet's theorem", proposition 1.2 states : "Suppose that $Y$ is a compact subset of a locally convex sapce $E$. A point $x$ in $E$ is in the closed convex hull $X$ of $Y$ iff there exists a probability measure $\mu$ on $Y$ which represents $x$." Now a Banach space is locally convex and some compact set are infinite dimensional right ?

Comment: The setting that you consider should be simple: Show that if $A \subset E$ is Borel, then so is $Y \cap A$ as a subset of $Y$. Then simply define $\mu(A)=\mu(Y \cap A)$.

Comment: @user953376 Yes I agree, I think I didn't explain well what I mean by extension, it is an extension on the topology, not the values. So for instance suppose I have the existence of a measure $\mu$ on a weakly compact subset of my Banach space. Then $\mu$ is a function of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the weak topology. The question is of the type, can I "extend" this measure to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the strong topology. This would lead to being able to have a statement about closed and bounded sets instead of compact.